# I am trying to print a simple input with the difference that it has a new line character in the end

Tags: c++, string, input, printing, newline

```cpp
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        cout << input << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

input:

```
Hello, World! (with a new line in the end)
```

output:

```
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

When it should be:

```
Hello, World!

Hello, World!

Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::getline()` swallows the trailing line break, it is not part of the returned `std::string` value.

`std::endl` outputs a single line break, and then flushes the output.  That is why you are getting the output you see:

```
Hello, World!<line break>
Hello, World!<line break>
Hello, World!<line break>
```

So, simply write two line breaks instead, eg:

```cpp
std::cout << input << std::endl << std::endl;
```

Or:

```cpp
std::cout << input << '\n' << std::endl;
```

Or:

```cpp
std::cout << input << "\n\n" << std::flush;
```

Then you will get the output you want:

```
Hello, World!<line break>
<line break>
Hello, World!<line break>
<line break>
Hello, World!<line break>
<line break>
```

Comment: I understand, but the trick is that sometimes the input does contain the extra newline character, and sometimes it doesn't, therefore I cant manually add it to the print statement. I was wondering if there is a command that would capture the newline character when the input contains it

Comment: @Sara.S "*sometimes the input does contain the extra newline character*" - as I said, `getline()` will swallow it, the newline will not be in the returned `string`. "*sometimes it doesn't*" - then `getline()` will not exit, it will block until a newline is entered. If that is the case, then you can't use `getline()` to read your input. "*therefore I cant manually add it to the print statement.*" - yes, you can. If `getline()` exits without error, it means a newline was read, so you can write your own newline to the output.